# How to know whether VerticalScrollbar of list view is visible if its visibility is 'Auto' in c# wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `listview`(checked list) 
- which has `checkbox` on the header to select all items in the list

Now, I have concern that user should not be able to select the items which are not visible in the list (Hidden due to `VerticalScrollBar`)

I have 2 solutions for this problem

1. Select only those items which are visible in the list (which seems difficult)
2. Disable select all `checkbox` if there is vertical scroll bar visible

I am going for the 2nd solution in which 
I need to know whether `verticalScrollBar` is appeared or not.

How to know whether `VerticalScrollbar` of `ListView` is visible if its visibility is 'Auto'?

Comment: I would not do that. Concerning solution 1: 'Select all' should select all items, not only some of them. Concerning solution 2: 'Select all' is useful especially when there are many items, i.e. when there is a scrollbar. How about, instead, changing the description of your `CheckBox` saying 'select all <number> items' to give the user a hint that there is more than he can see?

Comment: If vertical scrollbar is there then that means there are items which are not visible and user don't want to take any action on the items which are not visible that's why I am implementing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ScrollViewer`

```
ScrollViewer sv = FindVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(myListView);
Visibility VerticalScrollbarVisibility = sv .ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility;
```

FindVisualChild implementation example from [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e359eb13-245d-4389-bbb5-2ec350a93f1f/accessing-the-scrollviewer-of-a-listview?forum=wpf)

```
private childItem FindVisualChild<childItem>(DependencyObject obj) 
       where childItem : DependencyObject

    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
            if (child != null && child is childItem)
                return (childItem)child;
            else
            {
                childItem childOfChild = FindVisualChild<childItem>(child);
                if (childOfChild != null)
                    return childOfChild;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Yes. it is 'ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility' which tells actual visibility of the scroll bar. Thank you so much.